# set enum variable with only a description vb.net

Tags: vb.net, enums

I'm trying to set and `enum` and all that is in the database is the description.

```
public enum testcode
   <Description("T60")> passed
end enum
```

Using this, it errors out.

> tcode = CType(System.Enum.Parse(GetType(testcode), tstcode), testcode)

How do I set tcode with only the desc of T60? I can't change anything about the enum or the database.

Comment: You cant parse from Description to Enum without iterating to find the matching Description.  If `testcode.passed` was defined as `testcode.T60`, your Enum.Parse should work.  The description could then be "passed" to be used elsewhere like in reports, CBOs etc...or you could write a TypeConverter

Comment: not sure that is. tcode is of type testcode. i have the desc of t60 and i want to set the variable of testcode to passed.

Comment: you need to get all the Descriptions into a Dictionary and look for the one you are after; pretty much what you would do in a `TypeConverter`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection(v=vs.110).aspx) for this to work.

> *GetType > GetFields > GetCustomAttributes*

Here's an example using `LINQ`:

```vb
Imports System.Reflection

Public Enum TestCode
    <Description("T60")> Passed
End Enum

Dim tcode As TestCode = (
        From field As FieldInfo In GetType(TestCode).GetFields()
        From attribute As DescriptionAttribute In CType(field.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DescriptionAttribute), False), DescriptionAttribute())
        Where attribute.Description = "T60"
        Select CType(field.GetValue(Nothing), TestCode)
    ).FirstOrDefault()
```